# Multiple Mobile Web URLs

Tags: facebook, mobile, web

Is there a way of having multiple URLs in the web url box (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOpqX.png)

I am testing locally but want to test it on the server too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't - what are you trying to achieve with that?

Facebook uses the `mobile web URL` to redirect any users who hit your canvas link (http://apps.facebook.com/YOURAPP) on mobile, so having multiple URLS there wouldn't work.

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/09/30/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) is an article from last year regarding `multiple domain names`.

When testing live and local, I'll normally have a live and a staging application set up and then simply switch my app Id and secret based on the `url`.